# List in list ajax success access

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I had a list I did this:
My Controller:

```
var sel = new {list , m};
return Json(sel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In Ajax success I did this to access to element Date:

```
          for (var i = 0; i < sel.list.length; i++) {
                                row.append($('<td>').text(sel.list[i].Date));
                                row.append($('<td>').html(sel.m));
                            }
```

But now my list  is  `List<List<Event>>`;
How can I access to element Date in cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 loops.

```
$.get("PahtToYourAjaxEndpoint", function(sel) {

        $.each(sel.list, function(a, b) {

            $.each(b, function (x, y) {
                console.log(y);
                //you can access y.properties here
                 row.append($('<td>').text(y.Date));
                 row.append($('<td>').html(sel.m));
            });

        });
});
```